# Incremental Controls for Textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some code that adds two buttons to increase and decrease the quantity of a text box that works fine. I'm trying to expand that code to work with multiple text boxes. Unfortunately, the names of the text boxes will vary from page to page, so I'm using a class name that's shared by all the text boxes and attempting to increment the text box that's closest to each of the incremental buttons but I'm getting NaN for the value of the text boxes.

Oddly enough, it doesn't generate any errors. The NaN is from the console.log line.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be much appreciative...

Single Instance (working) : http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/iaCAb

Multiple Instances (not so much...): http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/ytpCF

```
function increaseQty(e) {
    console.log("jQuery('.qty').prev().val() = " + jQuery('.qty').prev().val());
    var qtyTotal = parseInt(jQuery('.qty').prev().val());
    jQuery('.qty').prev().val(parseInt(jQuery('.qty').prev().val())+1);
}
```

Comment: There needs to be some use of `this` or `e.target` in there so you only operate on the item that you clicked on. `jQuery('.qty')` selects **all** the quantity fields, not just the one you clicked on. I'll never understand why jQuery beginners find this so hard to get.

Answer (score 0):

First bind the event handler like this: `jQuery('.increase').click(increaseQty);`
You should use the `this` keyword to get only the textbox near to the button pressed.
Then try this code:

```
function increaseQty(e) {
    var tb = jQuery(this).closest('input');
    tb.val(parseInt(tb.val()) + 1);
}
```

The `closest()` function searches for the closest parent element that matches the selector.

Comment: This won't work by itself, he needs to change how he binds the event. He's not calling `increaseQty` with the appropriate context.

Comment: It should be `jQuery('.increase').click(increaseQty)`

Comment: ok, I updated the code like you suggested:                  

    `jQuery('.increase').click(increaseQty);`
    
    `function increaseQty(e) {
        var tb = jQuery(this).closest('.qty');
        tb.val(parseInt(tb.val()) + 1);
    }`

But I wasn't getting any values or errors, so I added

    `console.log("tb.val = " + tb.val );`
    
and that outputs this:

    `tb.val = function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];... (continued)`

Comment: Hmmm... having some trouble with the formatting in the comments, but if you check out the CodePen it's all in there:
    http://codepen.io/Realto619/pen/mqKlB

Comment: @Realto619 It should be `console.log("tb.val = " + tb.val());`. If you log `tb.val`, it will give you the `.val()` function's definition. You have to do the function call `tb.val()` instead.